# pgsql internal and c stored procedure support - can they modify PostgreSQL internals?

Tags: database, postgresql

pgsql stored procedure has support for internal and [c](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/xfunc-c.html) languages.

These are very interesting, however I cannot find many examples of what they can do. Furthermore, I was wondering if they would allow for modifying (or overriding) some PostgreSQL internals through a stored procedure?

This would be a nice alternative to rebuilding the PostgreSQL source!

Comment: Postgres provides [hooks](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/e/e3/Hooks_in_postgresql.pdf) for various internal events, though most are undocumented outside of the source code itself. You can find examples of many of these being used in [contrib modules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html). What kind of modifications did you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the PostgreSQL C API documentation is in the source code comments. It can take a while to figure out how things fit together and how you can interact with the server if you want to do more than write custom functions or new data types.

You cannot simply replace an existing function in PostgreSQL using an extension. You need to rely on the existing extension points like the system catalogs, hooks, etc. In particular, look at `ProcessUtility_hook`, the `ExecutorStart_hook`, etc.

These hooks can override or extend PostgreSQL behaviour.

In some other places it's not possible to override existing behaviour and you can only extend it. It depends on what you're trying to do.

There are a number of useful facilities like dynamic shared memory, background workers, `shared_preload_libraries` etc, allowing you to build larger and more complex extensions that do work independently of individual database sessions.

Start by reading the PostgreSQL manual sections on postgres internals. Then read some of the extensions in contrib/ . Then the general PostgreSQL developer documentation, some conference presentations related to PostgreSQL development, etc.

There isn't presently a single library of detailed how-to documentation for extensions.